# Shock formation in traffic flow equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Consider the PDE initial value problem
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(1-2u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x),$$ with the initial conditions for traffic congestion:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} & \text{if }\left|x\right|\ge 1\\
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{5}{3}-\left| x \right| \right) &\text{if } \left|x\right|\le 1\\
\end{cases}$$

This equation can be solved by the method of characteristics to obtain $$u(x,t)=f(x)+f(x-t(1+2u))$$

Now to find the time $t_s$ and position $x_s$ of the initial shock formation, we can do the following:

$$u(x,t) = f(x)+f(\tau)$$
$$x=(1-2f(\tau))t+\tau$$
$$u_x(x,t) = f'(x) + f'(\tau)\tau_x$$
$$1=-2tf'(\tau)\tau_x+\tau_x=\tau_x(1-2tf'(\tau))$$
$$\tau_x=\frac{1}{1-2tf'(\tau)}$$
$$u_x = f'(x)+\frac{f'(\tau)}{1-2tf'(\tau)}$$

Now to find the time and position of the initial shock formation, we need

$$t_s=\min_\tau\left( -\frac{1}{f'(\tau)} \right)$$

But the question is: how do we find $f(\tau)$?

Comment: Well if you have $f(x)$, $f(\tau)$ is the same, just replace $x$ by $\tau$ :-)

Comment: $x$ and $\tau$ are two completely different variables here. $\tau = x-(1-2u)t$.

Comment: *If* you last equation is filly correct (I didn't check the above math), it does not matter. What matters is the definition of $f$. You can express $f'$ "easily" from the definition of $f$, then plug that in the last equation, find it's minimum (if any/if it exists) by minimizing over $\tau$ and that will give you $t_s$. I didn't fully understand the math above though so maybe the last equation means different to you.

Comment: @sequence : did you check if your result $u(x,t)=f(x)+f(x-t(1+2u))$ agrees with the PDE ? You just have to put it into the PDE and see if it is satisfied. If you had done this check, you would have seen that your result is false.

Comment: @JJacquelin thanks for pointing this out. I've tried to substitute the following solution: $u(x,t)=f(x-t(1-2u))$ and it worked. I think I misplaced the sign somewhere. But I'm concerned about the initial traffic conditions for $f(x)$. How do we then add it to the equation?

Comment: Now, $u(x,t)=f(x-t(1-2u))$ is OK. In the wording of your question, you should correct the equation $u(x,t)=f(x)+f(x-t(1+2u))$ which is false : why is there $f(x)$ in it ?.

Comment: Right, I seem to have gotten entangled in the functions. So, then, we don't have to add the $f(x)$. The piecewise function for $f(x)$ is just defined for $t=0$. I will try to solve for $f'(\tau)$ and will post about my results.

Comment: @JJacquelin it's still not clear how to find $f'(\tau)$ from the expression $u_x = \frac{f'(\tau)}{1-2tf'(\tau)}$. We don't have an explicit definition for $u_x$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you because $\tau$ isn't defined and I don't understand what you do with $f'(t)$ since $f(x)$ isn't function of $t$.

Comment: @JJacquelin $\tau = x-t(1-2u))$.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of the PDE is :
$$u(x,t)=F(x-t(1-2u))$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Do not confuse $F$ with $f$ appearing in the initial condition :
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} & \text{if }\left|x\right|\ge 1\\
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{5}{3}-\left| x \right| \right) &\text{if } \left|x\right|\le 1\\
\end{cases}$$
The initial condition is : $u(x,0)=F(x)=f(x)$ which determines $F$ as :
$$F(X)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} & \text{if }\left|X\right|\ge 1\\
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{5}{3}-\left| X \right| \right) &\text{if } \left|X\right|\le 1\\
\end{cases}$$
In the particular solution fitting to the initial condition, $X\neq x$ but $X=x-t(1-2u)$
$$u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} & \text{if }\left|x-t(1-2u)\right|\ge 1\\
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{5}{3}-\left| x-t(1-2u) \right| \right) &\text{if } \left|x-t(1-2u)\right|\le 1\\
\end{cases}$$
You see that it is very different from the cases $|x|\ge 1$ and $|x|\le 1$ because $u$ is involved into them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch of the characteristic curves $x(t) = (1-2f(x_0))t+x_0$ in the $x$-$t$ plane:

[image: characteristics]

Characteristics seem to intersect at $t=1$. This can be recovered via the expression of the *breaking time*
\begin{aligned}
t_s &= \frac{-1}{\min\, (1-2f)'(x)} \\
&= \frac{1/2}{\max f'(x)} \\
&= 1 \, .
\end{aligned}

N.B. : this is the LWR traffic flow model.