# PDE $u_t+(1+u)u_x=0$ and method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Just started a course on PDE, and I'm trying to understand a specific (perhaps trivial) point in using method of characteristics in solving equations of the form $u_t+h(u)u_x=0$ where $h(u)$ is some function of $u$. Specifically, I was given the problem

$u_t+(1+u)u_x=0$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$

where

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & |x|>1\\
2-|x| & |x|\leq1
\end{cases}$

I followed an example shown to us in class, to reach the (perhaps wrong) conclusion that $u(x,t)=f(x-(1+u)t)$. From here, I'm stuck. 
The question given to me was to describe and analyze the cahracteristics curves and the solution, but I can't understand how we can disgard the recursive quality of the solution.
Trying to figure this, I saw two previously answered problems on this site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884821/shock-formation-in-traffic-flow-equation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740282/method-of-characteristics-for-traffic-flow-equation), but in both, there isn't a detailed explenation on my specific problems, only final or patial.
Will appreciate a detailed explentaion / a method to approaching this step of the problem.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202407) and use the piecewise expression of $f$ to solve the equation $u = f(x-(1+u)t)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$u_t+(1+u)u_x=0$$
Characteristic system of ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1+u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
First characteristic equation from $du=0$
$$u=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1+u}=\frac{dx}{1+c_1}$

$\frac{x}{1+c_1}=t+c_2$
$$\frac{x}{1+u}-t=c_2$$
General solution expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$\boxed{\frac{x}{1+u}-t=F(u)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined in order to satisfy the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ .

Condition : $\frac{x}{1+f(x)}-0=F(f(x))$

Let $\quad X=f(x)\quad$ and the inverse function $\quad x=f^{-1}(X)$
$$\frac{f^{-1}(X)}{1+X}=F(X)$$
So the function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=u$

$F(u)=\frac{f^{-1}(u)}{1+u}$

$$\frac{x}{1+u}-t=\frac{f^{-1}(u)}{1+u}$$
$$f^{-1}(u)=x-(1+u)t$$
The inverse function is :
$$u=f\big(x-(1+u)t\big)$$

Answer (score 2):

A good approach is to focus on concepts rather than steps: the concept here is that $u$ is constant along characteristics. So, start with a point on the $x$ axis, say $(x_0,0)$ and ask yourself what the value of $u$ is there. Then $u$ will have the same value along the characteristic starting at $(x_0,0)$. What is that characteristic? We know it has slope $(1+u)$, where $u$ is the value you just found, and we know one point that it goes through. Therefore you can describe that characteristic. Therefore you can describe all characteristics.